# ¿Cómo hacer actualizaciones a mi cliente sin parar tomcat?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, tomcat, glassfish

Tengo una aplicación web en producción en Java con un servidor tomcat, últimamente hemos estado haciendo actualizaciones pero siempre nos toca decirle al cliente que realizaremos una actualización y pues el cliente se queda sin trabajar todo ese tiempo hasta que terminamos. Hay alguna forma de evitar esto mientras se realiza la actualización?

Comment: Buenas por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: El deploy de un war deberia llevar segundos, y deberia hacerse (salvo emergencias) en horarios en que "el cliente" no trabaja.

Comment: Tal como dice @leonbloy, usualmente los pases a producción deberían ser en horarios que no impacte el trabajo del cliente. Si el cliente quiere o necesita que los cambios estén ASAP, debe comprender los riesgos de los mismos. Los pases a producción son una parte más de nuestras vidas de developers que nos vuelve noctámbulos

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Comment: Como ya te lo mencionaron, hacer un despligue a producción regularmente se hace en horario que no impacte la  operación del cliente( madrugada o fin de semana), ahora si el cliente quiere los despliegues en horario laboral, sería tener un ambiente COB(Sitio alterno que funciona mientras producción está abajo) @OscarMera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por experiencia propia, no es recomendable hacer actualizaciones al ambiente productivo en horas laborales, debería existir un plan del despliegue, si continuan con estas prácticas, podrian pensar en implementar algún balanceador como Nginx, y montar 2 servidores de aplicación.
Así  cuando actualicen uno, el otro sigue en la batalla, despues bajan ambos servicios, para entrar en funcionamiento la nueva actualización.
Aunque hay que tener cuidado siempre que se realice un pase a producción.
O también podrian probar con Apache kafka, que es una propuesta muy interesante para lo que necesitas.

[Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)

Saludos!